# Two color different for datagrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like to set different background color on my datagrid. I would like two colors.
A color XXXX for the first row, a YYYY for the second, the XXXXX for the third, etc...

I tried to create a style using AlternationIndex, but i see the same color on the rows.

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot :)

```
   <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#9f3131"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F9F99F"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F9F99F" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Red" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="20" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with [DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.alternatingrowbackground.aspx)?

Comment: Have you set [AlternationCount Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount.aspx) in your scenario?

Comment: Also, if you set a background value on the control outside of the style, that overrides any setter values. You'd have to make sure there's no local value, which means you need a setter for every alt row.

Answer (score 3):

[DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.alternatingrowbackground.aspx)

```
<Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#9f3131"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `AlternationCount` property on your `DataGrid` to 2.

And also change your style to set a color for the second `AlternationIndex`.

```
<Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="XXXXX"/>
</Trigger>

<Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="YYYYY"/>
</Trigger>
```

Hope this helps!